# Given the pdf for one variable, how can I transform this into the pdf of another variable

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

I am considering the diffusion of a particle in 1-D subject to a potential. I have been able to compute the average position $<x> = f(t)$ of the particle as a function of time $t$ as well as the variance of the particle $<x^2> -<x>^2 = g(t)$ as a function of time. This means I can write the probability distribution function of the particle being at position $x$ at time $t$ as a gaussian:

$$P(x,t) = \frac{1}{g(t) \sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp\bigg[ -\frac{1}{2} \frac{(x - f(t))^2}{g(t)^2} \bigg]$$

However the quantity I'm interested in is the PDF in terms of time $t$. More concretely I want to compute the PDF for how long it takes to travel between two points e.g. $x_i$ and $x_f$ which I can assume for now is just a gaussian e.g.

$$\mathcal{P}(x_i,t) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp\bigg[ -\frac{1}{2} \frac{(t - <t>)^2}{\sigma^2} \bigg]$$

which will clearly have the boundary condition $$\mathcal{P}(x_f,t) = \delta (t) $$ as if it's already at $x_f$ the travel time will be zero.

In essence I am trying to work out how $<t>$ and $\sigma$ relate to $f(t)$ & $g(t)$. I guess that $<t>$ is the value of $t$ such that $f(t) = x_f$ but I'm not sure this is the case? It's even less clear to me how to relate $g(t)$ to $\sigma$.

Phrased another way I want to turn the probability that enters the Fokker-Planck equation into the probability for the first-passage time problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so in case comes across this question and also wants to know the answer here is how I figured it out. The procedure is outlined in N. G. Van Kampen, Stochastic Processes in Physics and Chemistry. Elsevier, 2007.

We wish to compute the first-passage time (FPT) probability $\rho (\mathcal{N})$ that $x_2$ is reached between time $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{T} + \mathrm{d}\mathcal{T}$ given that at some initial time the particle is at $x_1$. This FPT probability can be related to the Fokker-Planck probability $\mathcal{P}(x,t)$ using:

$\int_{\mathcal{T}}^{\infty} \rho (t) \mathrm{d}t = \int_{x_2}^{\infty}P(x,\mathcal{T})\mathrm{d}x 
\quad \Rightarrow \quad \rho (\mathcal{T}) = -\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \mathcal{T}} \int_{x_2}^{\infty}P(x,\mathcal{T})\mathrm{d}x $

Therefore if you know the Fokker-Planck probability you can work out the FPT probability. For more details of this in practice and the application of this problem to Renormalisation Group techniques and the early universe can be found in our paper here https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.09649